# SPNEGO on Bluemix Liberty

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, spnego

On the Bluemix Liberty feature list, it says Spnego-1.0 is supported.  Does anyone have any Bluemix documentation (not plain Liberty, because this would mean I installed the Liberty server on my own enterprise domain) on how to even begin to use this?  It seems to me that if SPN are locked down to a domain name, how would this even work for an app running on a domain such as this: "www.ng.bluemix.net"?

Does this mean there is a requirement to have Bluemix infrastructure installed onto our enterprise infrastructure to even begin thinking about Spnego?

Comment: Way out of my element, but a good question!  Have you looked at the "secure gateway service" to tie into your KDC when hosted on bluemix?

Answer (score 0):

SPNEGO makes sense if you're trying to achieve SSO between say a Microsoft Desk Top and say a WASaaS (WAS or Liberty) running a web app in a Softlayer VM behind a private firewall, then a SPNEGO solution would work. In a more public setting, OpenID Connect should be considered as an option.

If SPNEGO really needs to be used, see [**the Liberty documentation**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_spnego_config.html?lang=en). You can then customize a Liberty `server.xml` file in Bluemix to get this to work. To use a custom Liberty `server.xml` file, see the info noted [**under standalone applications**](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/liberty/index.html).